# Saving data from forms

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, database, forms

Already have a functioning website built with HTML, CSS, JavaScript and PHP for sending information from a contact form. Now have another basic form that visitors can submit information for us to contact them regarding a product launch in the near future.

Form is currently built using HTML and input fields (see below)

```
<input id="phone2” type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone Number" />
```

We need to collect this data and store it in a database. Is the best way to do this using Rails? Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: If the rest of the site is in PHP you're probably best off sticking with PHP.

Comment: The only thing currently in PHP is the contact form being saved.

Comment: Sorry new developer and don't want to screw up existing site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your existing site is flat files meaning PHP and HTML are mixed into both and no MVC framework is used then I would recommend just applying you custom php code when the form is submitted, so on $_POST capture the data and submit to the DB, job done.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was trying to point out to my friend. There really isn't a need for an MVC framework on this site, correct? It would just complicate things and be much more work.

Comment: I'm not familiar with PHP but it doesn't look to difficult to capture form data

Comment: If you guys are brand new to PHP then please stay away from MVC until you are comfortable with PHP!!!

Comment: any great tutorials on capturing form details?